# Fixing bad practices with authorization and pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

I'm using pundit in a rails app to do authorization and I'm not sure what is the appropriate way to go about this with the setup I have.

I have a namepsaced controller

```rb
class Rentals::OffersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rental
  before_action :set_offer, only: [:accept, :reject]

  def index
    @offers = @rental.offers
    authorize [:rental @rental]
  end
end
```

and also a namespaced policy

```rb
class Rentals::OfferPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    def index?
    end
end
```

and what I would like to achieve is to authorize with the `@rental` instance to see if it's created by the user. However this `authorize [:rental @rental]` does not work as it's not looking for the `Rentals::OfferPolicy`.

I've got this to work by using a `RentalPolicy`'s `edit?` method as

```rb
class RentalPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

    def edit?
        user.present? && user.id == record.id
    end
end
```

and then in `Rentals::OffersController` I have

```rb
class Rentals::OffersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rental
  before_action :set_offer, only: [:accept, :reject]

  def index
    @offers = @rental.offers
    authorize @rental, :edit?, policy_class: RentalPolicy
  end
end
```

but I feel like I'm going against the practices of pundit. How should I achieve this with the way it should be done?

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that `authorize [:rental @rental]` causes a syntax error a big issue with this code is that you're not actually namespacing your code correctly. `class Rentals::OffersController` does not reopen the `Rentals` module and set the module nesting so when you reference `OfferPolicy` Ruby will just look in  `Rentals::OffersController` and the root namespace.

```ruby
# bad
class Rentals::OffersController < ::ApplicationController
  puts Module.nesting # [ Rentals::OffersController]
  puts OfferPolicy.name # uninitialized constant Rentals::OffersController::OfferPolicy (NameError) 
end
```

```ruby
# Good
module Rentals
  class OffersController < ::ApplicationController
    puts Module.nesting # [Rentals, Rentals::OffersController]
    puts OfferPolicy.name # it can correctly find other constants in the Rentals module
  end
end
```

Using the scope resolution operator (`::`) is not as many people have been missled to believe just an alternative style of writing nested classes/modules and unfortunately the Rails generators and guides just make the confusion worse. It is not recommended by [the Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition).

Instead you should explicitly nest modules/classes.

```ruby
module Rentals
  class OffersController < ::ApplicationController
    before_action :set_rental
    before_action :set_offer, only: [:accept, :reject]

    def index
      @offers = @rental.offers
      authorize @rental
    end
  end
end
```

```ruby
module Rentals
  class OfferPolicy < ::ApplicationPolicy
    class Scope < Scope
      def resolve
        if user
          # this ensures that we are scoped to current_user, without relying on other policies
          scope.joins(:rental).where(rental: { user_id: user.id })
        else
          # no user, no offers
          scope.none
        end
      end
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Since this actually sets the module nesting to `[Rentals, Rentals::OffersController ]` it will look for the constant `RentalPolicy` in `Rentals` before looking in the root namespace (main).

Maybe someday Ruby will actually have a separate namespace operator that lets you define nested classes without the excess indentation but until then  you should ensure that your code doesn't do suprising and buggy constant lookups.

Comment: Make sure you apply this to the rest of your codebase such as the model. Rubocop can help.

Comment: I might have not understood correctly what you meant. What's the difference between calling `Rentals::OffersController` rather than having the module block?

Comment: Rather I would be interested in what kind of changes would I have to make if I change from `Rentals::OffersController` to the module block.

Comment: Also it seems that this will cause problems as `Rental` is also a class that has many offers(?).

Comment: I added a concrete example that shows the difference in how module nesting effects how Ruby does constant lookup. "Also it seems that this will cause problems as Rental is also a class that has many offers(?)." no - thats not a real concern.

Comment: would `OfferPolicy` at the top level also solve everything as well, regardless of nesting.